# Is there an official comprehensive list of E-numbers?

Tags: resources, websites, additives

Does an official comprehensive list of the E-numbers exists?

I'm thinking of something along what [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_number) provides:

- Number
- Role
- Name
- Description
- Approval
- Notes

An example of an entry could be:

- E110
- Colour
- Sunset Yellow FCF
- Used to grand a yellow-orange colour
- Approved in the European Union, approved in the United States of America, banned in Norway
- Products in the European Union require warnings and its use is being phased-out

These informations can be found scattered around the internet, but I've not yet been able to find a single page containing all of them besides the Wikipedia article (not that I've anything against Wikipedia, but I'd like an official source instead of a page anyone can edit and whose accuracy can't be guaranteed), lLooking up the informations through 4/5 documents every time is impractical.

At the moment I've been able to find these official documents:

- [Class names and the international numbering system for food additives](http://www.codexalimentarius.org/download/standards/13341/CXG_036e.pdf)
- [Codex general standard for food additives](http://www.codexalimentarius.net/gsfaonline/docs/CXS_192e.pdf)
- [Current EU approved additives and their E Numbers](http://www.food.gov.uk/policy-advice/additivesbranch/enumberlist)

Comment: I don't know that such a single compendium exists, but it seems like it would be a worthy addition to Wikipedia if you were willing to compile it from the disparate sources.

Comment: I'm guessing the really unlikely thing here is to find an official source with information for both the EU and the US. Something published by the US government is a lot less likely to also have the EU information. (And if it does, it's not "official" information for the EU.)

Comment: As Jefromi says, docs are official in different juristictions, I suggest to look at the wikipedia pages notes, a quick check gave me [this](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CONSLEG:1995L0002:20060815:EN:PDF) that looks quite good and comprehencive (but to many for me to check..), but if you want US official you might have to find another link.

Comment: There is a book called food additives which contains many of them. They may have other references that'd be useful.

Comment: I'm not sure if the US even uses them normally.  (we have 'yellow dye #5' and names like that over here).  Another place that you might try asking is on [OpenData.SE](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4):

http://www.ukfoodguide.net/enumeric.htm

The E numbers are standardized across all EU nations.  I'm not even aware if non EU nations use them?